# how to correctly format a hosts file - bash

Tags: bash, unix, hadoop, sed

I'm trying to create a `Hadoop` cluster, and in order to do so, I have to format my `/etc/hosts` file to just contain the ip addresses of the nodes in the cluster. Currently it looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

## vagrant-hostmanager-start
<ipaddress1>   namenode
<ipaddress2>  secondarynamenode
<ipaddress3>  slave1
<ipaddress4>   slave2
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

At the end, I just want to leave it as

```
## vagrant-hostmanager-start
<ipaddress1>   namenode
<ipaddress2>  secondarynamenode
<ipaddress3>  slave1
<ipaddress4>   slave2
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

How can accomplish that using `sed`, `grep`, `cat` or any `Bash` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use sed like this:

```
sed -n '/## vagrant-hostmanager-start/,/## vagrant-hostmanager-end/p' /etc/hosts
## vagrant-hostmanager-start
<ipaddress1>   namenode
<ipaddress2>  secondarynamenode
<ipaddress3>  slave1
<ipaddress4>   slave2
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

Comment: And how to pipe it back to the file /etc/hosts? I only want the file /etc/hosts to contain the results of sed -n '/## vagrant-hostmanager-start/,/## vagrant-hostmanager-end/p' /etc/hosts

Comment: You can use inline sed command: `sed -i.bak -n '/## vagrant-hostmanager-start/,/## vagrant-hostmanager-end/p' /etc/hosts`